# AngularJS ignores disabled on post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created  a  directive to set inputs disabled on boxes which aren't double clicked as "active". I have a problem where AngularJS still passes those inputs which have been disabled to a scope function.

**Basic input HTML:**

```
 <div class="selectable-boxes" toggle-inputs>
        <div class="box selected">
            <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First" name="f1" data-ng-model="fields.information.f1">
                </div>
                ...
```

All named f1, f2, f3..

**Directive:**

```
app.directive( 'toggleInputs', function() {
    return {
        link: function(Scope, element, attrs) {
            var $element = element;

            $element.find('.box').bind('dblclick', function () {
                $element.find('.box').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                toggleInputDisabled();
            });

            function toggleInputDisabled() {
                $element.find('.box').each(function () {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', !$(this).hasClass('selected')).attr('data-ng-disabled', 'isDisabled');
                });
            }

            toggleInputDisabled();
        }
    };
});
```

The directive works fine. It disables fields and adds ng-disabled="'isDisabled' and I've set `$scope.isDisabled = true;`. However, these values still get passed forward on a $scope function. Why?

```
Object {f1: "1", f2: "2", f3: "3", f10: "4", f11: "5"…}
```

Comment: Scope.abc model will always contain some value in it. By disabling you are not removing the 2 way binding.

Comment: Are you saying I need to disable the data-ng-model attribute to disable the values from passing forward? I believe I can do that and it actually solves my other problem. I just don't know if it will affect the inputs meaning if I type something in, then remove the attribute, then put it back, the value will be gone?

Comment: When you create a model, and add any value to it, it stores it till it is changed, and if by any means on view or in controller, whenever you will change it to any value, the model will be updated. You cannot stop that from happening.

Comment: Then what is your solution to this particular problem? I need to bind these inputs to ng-model because i need my ng-click="function()" to pass those fields onto the function as I have multiple submit buttons in one form. Each have their own params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came up with a solution to go around this particular problem. The issue seems to be with `ng-model` as suggested in above comments and that it creates a binding that's hard to actually remove and I need that binding to actually use `ng-click="function(fields)"`.

So I went and created a directive which then manipulates scope to add another 'replaced' parameter to the object tree that I'm using. I then check if that exists and use those new values, but there was another issue with this.

I had to use setTimeout(function() { }, 100); inside the controller function to actually find these new values, because they could not be found otherwise.

```
app.directive( 'buttonClick', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
          scope.fields.information.replaced = {};

          var i = 0;

          $('.selectable-boxes .box.selected input').each(function() {
                scope.fields.information.replaced['f' + i] = $(this).val();
                i++;
          });

          scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using ng-disabled on the tag, rather than the hard to read jQuery style expression you have gone for:

[NG Disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

So the attribute already is on the input box and is just toggled by the code, 
attribute = logic expression

This is true angular at work and will do all the disabling for you. Post-fixing the attribute I'd imagine will lead to more code and potentially more problems.

Plunkr example, taken from my comment:

[Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pzM8D7)

HTML part:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First" name="f1" 
        data-ng-model="fields.information.f1" ng-show="!hideem" ng-disabled="disabled">
   </div>
```

And the two controls:

```
Disable <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled" name="diablethem" id="disablethem"/>

Hide <input type="checkbox" ng-model="hideem" name="hideem" id="hideem"/>
```

Init your items as required:

```
  $scope.disabled=false;
  $scope.hideem= false;
```

Comment: @Rcls No, you don't. Adding an attribute is not the same as using a directive. `.attr('data-ng-disabled', 'isDisabled')` is pointless.

Comment: Please provide an example as to how this would work. I didn't quite understand what you meant but I added an data-ng-disabled attribute to all HTML elements, then I flip that to isEnabled \ isDisabled from directive. No effect.

Comment: You can see a very simple startup here: https://plnkr.co/edit/pzM8D7 if you check disabled your form field is not posted. As you can see it's far less code than zooming through DOM fields. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You must recompile the element after setting or changing the attribute by jQuery:

```
function toggleInputDisabled() {
    $element.find('.box').each(function () {
        $(this).find(':input')
            .attr('disabled', !$(this).hasClass('selected'))
            .attr('data-ng-disabled', 'isDisabled');
        });
    }
    $compile($element)(scope);
}
```

Don't forget the dependency:

```
app.directive( 'toggleInputs', function($compile) { … }
```

Comment: Why mix jQuery in Angular, when you can use the compile function in Angular by directive ???

Comment: Because documentation on this subject is very scarce and this is the first time I read about $compile. I find the Angular way is more complicated than jQuery by alot even if people claim it to be better.

Comment: I asked the question from @Rwam ! ;-/